# Cannot Find specific Item Id contained in Menu.xml From MainActivity

Tags: java, android-studio

This error is so dumb I cannot really think of a reason why it's happening. I apologize if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find this particular problem.

I got a menu file with a few Items in it which looks like this.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_meal_categories"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_fire"
        android:title="Meal Categories"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_meal_countries"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_fire"
        android:title="Tasty Countries"/>
</group>
```

I implement the logic for the Menu Items in The MainActivity, I can navigate through activities without problems and everything works smoothly but this particular nav_meal_categories cannot be found.

I tried rebuilding the project, cleaning it and restarting AndroidStudio but nothing changed. I also tried to add other items to the menu.xml and to my surprise they could also not be found.

Is it some Android Studio problem or did I code something wrong?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer and see  if that works.
I know it's a dumb answer, but oh well...

Comment: Not a solution unfortunately.

Comment: Ok here are few 'more sensible' things that you can try:
1. Make sure the menu file is inside 'menu' resource folder.
2. Recreate the whole menu file.
3. Trigger change in dependency in build.gradle file so you can rebuild the gradle.
4. Rebuild, Clean Build, Invalidate Cache, Invalidate Cache & Restart (Which you have done most already)
5. Update Android Studio (And yes this has helped me quite a times in the past)